# Checkbox count to store in MySql DB PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have two checkbox filter and I want to store the count of both checkbox checked each time in seperate column in mysql table.

can someone help here to get count of checkbox checked each time and store to DB.

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="Click" name="Click" onclick="applyConsolidatedFilter()">
  <label for="Click">Clicked</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Click1" name="Click1" onclick="applyConsolidatedFilter()">
  <label for="Click1">Clicked1</label>
```

````
   
   var checkedFilter = 'checkedfilter=';
   var clk = document.getElementById("Click");
   var clk1 = document.getElementById("Click1");

if ( clk.checked){
       checkedFilter = checkedFilter.concat('Click,');
   }
if ( clk1.checked){
       checkedFilter = checkedFilter.concat('Click1,');
   }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but if what you wan't is to know how many checkboxes where checked :

```js
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("[type='checkbox']");
let count = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
    if(checkboxes[i].checked) count++;
}
```

this is gonna give you the number of checked checkboxes. Then you can add a hidden field to your form:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="checked_checkboxes" id="count">
```

and populate it with you js value :

```js
document.getElementById("count").value = count
```

Comment: I have 4 checkboxes, I want to update how many times each checkboxes clicked. Ex: checkbox1 clicked 5 times, in DB it should be 5 in checkbox1 column.  checkbox2 clicked 10times, count in db column is 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script which will create hidden inputs and increase their values when a checkbox is clicked :

```js
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('type="checkbox"]');
let clickCounts = [];

for(let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
    clickCounts[i] = 0;
    let input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    input.setAttribute("name", `checkbox_${i}_count`);
    input.setAttribute("id", `checkbox_${i}_count`);
    document.body.append(input);
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
        clickCounts[i]++;
        document.getElementById(`checkbox_${i}_count`).value = clickCounts[i];
    })
}
```

these values will then be available in php's

```php
$_POST
```

when submitting your form